# GCP Cloud SDK install fails in MAC

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Unable to install gcloud sdk using package "google-cloud-sdk-307.0.0-darwin-x86_64.tar.gz" downloaded from gcloud.
Supported Python versions are 3.5 to 3.7, and 2.7.9 or higher

Does it mean Python 3.7.4 is not supported?

```
enter code here
```

```html
$ python3 -V
Python 3.7.4

$ which -a python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3

$ ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/spalani/Documents/DownloadPackages/./google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 12, in <module>
    import bootstrapping enter code here
  File "/Users/spalani/Documents/DownloadPackages/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 39, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core import config
  File "/Users/spalani/Documents/DownloadPackages/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/config.py", line 33, in <module>
    from oauth2client import client
  File "/Users/spalani/Documents/DownloadPackages/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/oauth2client/client.py", line 39, in <module>
    from oauth2client import transport
  File "/Users/spalani/Documents/DownloadPackages/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/oauth2client/transport.py", line 17, in <module>
    import httplib2
  File "/Users/spalani/Documents/DownloadPackages/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/httplib2/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from httplib2.python3.httplib2 import *
  File "/Users/spalani/Documents/DownloadPackages/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/httplib2/python3/httplib2/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 7):

Regarding your question “Does it mean Python 3.7.4 is not supported?”
According to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install):

> Cloud SDK runs on Linux, macOS, and Windows. Cloud SDK requires Python. Supported versions are 3.5 to **3.7**, and 2.7.9 or higher.

So, it seems that it is supported for the Cloud SDK installation.

On the other hand, I have found the following [guide](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/startup) to configure the Python interpreter, it could help you to set it properly.

Also, It appears that the [recommended option](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install#installation_options) to install SDK on MacOS is through the interactive installer.

> For Windows and macOS interactive installations, and all other use cases, run the interactive installer to install the latest release of Cloud SDK.

The steps to install it using the [Google Cloud SDK installer](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive) are:

1. Enter the following at a command prompt:

`curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash`

2. Restart your shell:

`exec -l $SHELL`

3. Run `gcloud init` to initialize the `gcloud` environment:

`gcloud init`

I hope you find this information useful.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem to me. I suspect the issue is with the OpenSSL version of *macOS* (mine is v1.1.1); stack-trace returns `bootstrapping/install.py`, `core/config.py`, `oauth2client/client.py`, `httplib2/python3/httplib2/__init__.py`, `/opt/pkg/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so`.

Comment: thanks a lot bro! Saves me last two days trouble