# Getting Error While Google Cloud CLI installation - No module named 'oauthlib.oauth2

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, apple-m1

I'm trying to install Google Cloud CLI in my MacBook pro (M1). I have downloaded the M1 version of gCLI SDK for installation.

A bit about my environment:

- python version 3.9.5 (environment managed by pyenv)
- currently installed `oauthlib` version `oauthlib==3.2.2`

Here's the error I'm getting:

[image: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauthlib.oauth2' during gCLI Installation]

I've also tried installing python-oauth2 to resolve the problem, but no luck. Any pointers will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't solve this problem, but finally figured out a way to install google-cloud-sdk in Mac following these steps: 


-Enter the following at a command prompt: `curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash`

-Restart your shell: `exec -l $SHELL`

-Run gcloud init to initialize the gcloud environment: `gcloud init`

Thanks to this thread for solving the installation problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63586850/gcp-cloud-sdk-install-fails-in-mac

Comment: It is still the same error and your solution from the comment worked out for me. Thanks